# Monitor files added to directory for size (Bash)

Tags: bash, stat, inotify

I would like to monitor a directory and break another program if too small files are added. Here is my prototype:

```
inotifywait -r -m -e modify . | 
   while read _ _ file; do 
       if (( $(stat --printf="%s" "$file") << 36500 )); then
          echo "break"
       fi
   done
```

But the line with the comparison operator doesn't work. Is it impossible to combine inline execution with a math operator or have I used it incorrectly?

Comment: "Less than" is just `<` in arithmetic context in Bash.

Comment: @7Reeds I'm pretty sure they just want to compare file size in bytes with "less than" and somehow ended up with `<<` instead of `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bash arithmetic](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) syntax indicates that this should be `(("$(stat --printf="%s" "$file")" < 36500))`. `<<` is sometimes used in mathematics to mean "much less than", but it's not well defined as you can imagine.